# Maximal protori in compact topological groups

Tags: topological-groups

I read the following proposition in the article in the link. Since $G$ itself is finite-dimensional, isn't the maximal protorus $T$ also finite-dimensional? In this case, $G$ becomes a Lie group. Isn't there something interesting here? Frankly, I don't fully understand the proposition.

**Proposition 3.5** Let $G$ be a compact connected group, and $T$ a maximal protorus in $G$. Then $G$ is a Lie group if and only if $T$ is finite dimensional.

https://nyaspubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1749-6632.1994.tb44147.x

[image]

Comment: The proposition you quote is obviously false (take $G=T$ to be a 1-dimensional solenoid). However the paper you link is behind a paywall, so I can't check whether some assumption is hidden, or if it is really the claimed statement. (It's indeed written this way [in the ZBmath review](https://zbmath.org/0935.22008).)

Comment: It seems that the authors of the paper to which the author of the question links consider the case of abelian groups to be obvious.

Comment: I think the dimension here is used in a different sense. From what I read in the article, it doesn't mention the dimension at all

Comment: @MehmetOnat, I don't think so. If they had a different meaning for "dimension," they would have said so.

Comment: Indeed the paper is incorrect. What the authors prove is that $G$ is Lie iff $T$ is Lie. Or also, that $G$ is Lie iff $Z(G)$ is Lie and $T$ is finite-dimensional.